# How to instantiate object of a Factorymethod pattern and and use that method in different classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, factory-pattern, factory-method

This is my BrowserRunnerFactory.cs where I have defined to choose chrome and Firefox browser:

```
public class BrowserRunnerFactory
{
    public static IBrowserInterface InitiateBrowser(BrowserType BrowserType)
    {

        switch (BrowserType)
        {
            case BrowserType.Chrome:
                return new ChromeRunner();
            case BrowserType.Firefox:
            default:
                return new FirefoxRunner();
        }
    }
```

I have called it and defined two different filed browser and driver in a calss baseInitializer.cs:

```
public void GetDriver()
    {
      if (browser is null)
        { 
            browser = 
            BrowserRunnerFactory.InitiateBrowser(BrowserType.Chrome);
            driver = browser.Driver;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to create automated testing and with **browser** I am trying to call chrome browser. And with the **driver** field I want to manipulate the selenium properties like driver.Manage(), driver.FindElement(By.Id()), driver.Close(),* etc.

---

So in the baseInitializer.cs class it is working fine. I am getting the value of both of the field browser and driver.
The **browser** filed should be called only once in the baseInitializer class such that the chrome Browser opens up to run all UI Automated Tests.

---

But when I try to call driver from a separate class say ClientTab.cs where I am trying to test some tab of a page like shown below:

```
BaseInitializer baseinItializer = new Baseinitializer();
public IWebDriver driver = null;
 public bool TabIsOpen()
    {
        driver = baseInitializer.driver; 
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        try
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(_configModel.NewRepository)).Click();
            return true;
                       }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Log("Error occured while looking for CLientTabId:" + 
             e.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
        }
    }
```

After I run the test I will get the NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
While Debugging I find that the driver is null. While I want the driver as defined in the GetDriver method

```
driver = browser.Driver()
```

I tried this design pattern for the first time and also I'm a beginner of in C#. So any feedback, as well as suggestion regarding my coding practices, would be so helpful.

Comment: you set `public IWebDriver driver = null;` and there's nothing that sets it to any other value... you are not calling `GetDriver` either... something is missing here.

Comment: @KirilS. I Added the missing part. But still driver is null. Please have a look again